# javascript - disable hyper link of a html frame from the other html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to disable the href link in this frame html file . I am able to get the element from other html file but I am not able to set attr or onclick prevent default.

```
<a id="StatusLink" href="/StatusFrame.html" target="detail"><i class="demo-icon icon-chart-line fa-fw"></i> System Status<span class="demo-icon icon-right-open-1"></span></a>

top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink")

top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink").attr("href", "http://the.new.url");
```

**TypeError: top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById(...).attr is not a function(…)**

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: Don't mix functions;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery method and you have a plain DOM element, so use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink").setAttribute("href", "http://the.new.url");
```

The above will work but it's more appropriate to set the property directly instead of through the attribute, so I would use:

```
top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink").href = "http://the.new.url";
```

If you are trying to disable the href then you can add a click handler to prevent default, and leave the href as is:

```
top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink").onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: How to enable the link again ?

Comment: Thanks MrCode ..It works ..Can I use the below for enable again? .. like top.window.frames[1].document.getElementById("StatusLink").onclick = function(){
           return true
        };